# Как определять что прислал юзер в tg aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Ку!

```
@dp.message_handler(state=CellarImport.check)
async def enter_volume(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    await state.update_data(answer4=answer)
    if answer == 'Отменить ❌':
        await message.answer('Вы возвращены в главное меню.', reply_markup=kbmain)
        await state.reset_state(with_data=False)
    if answer == 'Подтвердить ✅':
        await CellarImport.next()
        await message.answer(f"Отправь мне то, что надо будет разослать ", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

for i in range(0, cn):
    await bot.send_message(answerq[i], message.text)
```

**как мне сделать, чтобы если человек прислал гифку, фото или другой тип то он тоже пересылался? сейчас пересылается только текстовый тип сообщения.**

Comment: хендлер не получиться, т.к хендлер в хендлер нельзя встроить, либо я не знаю как встроить

Answer (score 1):

Да есть более простой способ и вот он:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.ANY)
```

Ловит все типы сообщений.

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'video', 'document'])
async def send_msg(message:types.Message):            
    if message.text:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, message.text)
    elif message.photo:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id, message.photo[-1].file_id)
    elif message.video:
        await bot.send_video(chat_id, message.video.file_id)
    elif message.document:
        await bot.send_document(chat_id, message.document.file_id)
    else:
        await message.answer('Error')
```

Как-то так делаю я, возможно есть более лаконичное решение.

Помимо прочего, если вам потребуется пересылать подпись к фото или видео, не забывайте добавлять `caption`

```
elif message.photo:
    cptn = message.caption
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id, message.photo[-1].file_id, caption = cptn)
elif message.video:
    cptn = message.caption
    await bot.send_video(chat_id, message.video.file_id, caption = cptn)
```